# Cassandra 3.0 and later require Java 8u40 or later

Tags: cassandra, java-home, cassandra-3.0

I'm trying to run cassandra 3.0 in datastax. But i'm getting an error saying 
Cassandra 3.0 and later require Java 8u40 or later.

I have installed java and moved the jdk1.8.0_65 to `/usr/local/java` and set JAVA_HOME to `/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_65`.

But I'm still facing the following error:

> Cassandra 3.0 and later require Java 8u40 or later.

Comment: What distribution are you using? I found a solution for this for Ubuntu, which I will write up if that would help.

Comment: I'm using datastax. Learning cassandra from there so using datastax distribution.

Answer (score 5):

I installed Cassandra 3.2 DataStax Distribution rpm on CentOS 7, and experienced the same problem. Cassandra startup script `/etc/rc.d/init.d/cassandra` finds `java` binary in the predefined path list only.

`JVM_SEARCH_DIRS="/usr/lib/jvm/jre /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.7.* /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.*/jre"`

If your java binary is `/usr/jdk64/jdk1.8.0_60/jre/bin/java`, append `/usr/jdk64/jdk1.8.0_60/jre` to `JVM_SEARCH_DIRS`, or make `/usr/lib/jvm/jre` symlink for `/usr/jdk64/jdk1.8.0_60/jre`.

Answer (score 3):

Check your java version. if your Java version is "1.8.0_40" later. 
goto this file apache-cassandra-3.7\conf\cassandra-env.ps1 and search this word JVM_VERSION.CompareTo("1.8.0_40") then change to your version.
For example if you use java 1.8.0_102 then change to JVM_VERSION.CompareTo("1.8.0_102").

Now, check. It will work.

Answer (score 2):

I typically solve this by adding my specific `JAVA_HOME` into the `$DSE_DIR/resources/cassandra/conf/cassandra.in.sh` and `$DSE_DIR/bin/dse.in.sh` scripts provided with `DataStax`.
Add: `JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_65` in each. (Or a `symlink`, if you want to be able to swap the JVM without re-editing these files.)

Answer (score 2):

The following works for me on a RHEL system:

```
yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk
ln -nfs /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64 /etc/alternatives/jre
ln -nfs /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64/bin/java /etc/alternatives/java
```

Comment: This solution worked for me on Amazon EC2 AMI, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I also have same problem. My solution is editing file apache-cassandra-3.7/bin/cassandra. Below line that contain "#!/bin/sh" (2nd line) you can put line like below

```
JAVA_HOME="/path/of/your/jdk"
```

example :

```
JAVA_HOME="/opt/jdk1.8.0_101"
```

Hope this solution can help you and other people

Answer (score 1):

1. Check first version of java using this command `java -version`
2. Check path of java using this command `echo $JAVA_HOME`

Comment: I rand `update-java-alternatives -s java-8-oracle` first, but that did not fix the softlink that `$JAVA_HOME` was pointing to (i.e. that was still on the OpenJDK)... fixing the softlink fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use following commands.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

Answer (score 0):

The *nodetool* might still be accessing the earlier java version, I too faced the same issue.

short do this

`sudo vim /etc/environment` add this line 
 JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java"

`source /etc/environment`

`echo $JAVA_HOME`

`nodetool status`

long do this

Please follow the steps [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-java-on-ubuntu-with-apt-get) to install and change the version of java installed in your system . Its explained very well.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use *alternatives* command:

```
$ nodetool
Cassandra 3.0 and later require Java 8u40 or later.
$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_151"

$ sudo yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk
... 
$ sudo alternatives --config java

There are 2 programs which provide 'java'.

Selection    Command
-----------------------------------------------
*+ 1           /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64/bin/java
2           /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64/bin/java

Enter to keep the current selection[+], or type selection number: 2

$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_151"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_151-b12)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.151-b12, mixed mode)
$ nodetool
usage: nodetool [(-p <port> | --port <port>)]
    [(-pwf <passwordFilePath> | --password-file <passwordFilePath>)]
    [(-h <host> | --host <host>)] [(-u <username> | --username <username>)]
    [(-pw <password> | --password <password>)] <command> [<args>]
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems, as if the `cassandra` service would pick up the Java version from [alternatives](https://linux.die.net/man/8/alternatives), only.

```
sudo alternatives --config java
```

... don't select Java 9 there.

```
sudo service cassandra start
```

`/etc/cassandra/default.conf/jvm.options` has further JVM parameters.